# What is a good solution for cross datacenter master-master replication?

Tags: database, cloud, distributed-system, multi-master-replication, nosql

Lets say we have a distributed system where data is sharded by user ids. In most cases each shard is changed by user who owns this shard. There are more then one datacenter and users are balanced between these datacenters using DNS, cookies or somehow else. I.e. in most cases every user is served by one datacenter. This means we can replicate data between datacenters in master-master manner. Of course conflicting writes are possible, but they are rare and could be resolved using, say, CRDTs or vector clocks. And if some datacenter fails users could be just redirected to other datacenters!

Are there any database capable to solve described problem? Maybe some services provided by AWS or Google Cloud offer a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the specific use case here, because of the way you may want to shard, but Aerospike has XDR where all clusters are peers.

- https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/xdr.html

All clusters will be "eventually consistent" using XDR because of speed-of-light delays, plus we batch the updates between datacenters. Yet within each cluster, the Aerospike DB will be immediately consistent.

Feel free to check out our docs for more answers:

- https://www.aerospike.com/docs/